# How do you load Employee objects into an ArrayList of Departments based on the department that employee belongs to?

Tags: java

I am in need of help! I have to complete a Java Assessment to get into this Java training program and my future is depending on this! Here is the terms of the assessment:
2. Create an Employee class with following attributes / variables:
    name
    age
    department

1. Create a class called Department which will contain a list of employees. 
   a) Department class will have a method which will return its employees ordered by age. 
   b) The value of department can be only one of the following values:
       “Accounting”
       “Marketing”
       “Human Resources”
       “Information Systems”
2. Create a static method in a separate class called PrimeAgeChecker to check if an employee’s age is prime number or not. This method should be able to accept an employee object as an argument to do the check.
3. Create a class called Company which will contain a list of departments. Create a main method in this class to load the following departments and corresponding employee information into the company:

I have literally been working on this for about a week and a half every day and every night and have not figured it out yet. Here is what I have so far:

```
package JAssessment;



public class Employees {
//fields
private String name; 
private int age;
public String employees;
public String department;

public String getDepartment(){
        return department;
    }
public Employees() 
{
    name = "unknown name";
    age = 3;
}
public void setAge(int age)
{
    this.age = age;
}
public int getAge() 
{
    return age;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public String toString()
{
    return this.getName() + " (" + this.getAge() + " Age)";
}
public void setDepartment(String d1) {
    this.department = d1;

}
public void setDeptName(String string) {
    string = string;

}   

}


package JAssessment;
import java.util.*;
public class Department {

Employees emp;
static ArrayList<Employees> employees;
String deptName;
    String department;

    public Department(String String) {
    this.deptName = deptName;

}

public String getDeptName() {
    return deptName;
}

public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
    this.deptName = deptName;
}

public static void addEmployeeX(Employees e)
{   
    //put the employee age's in ascending order
    if (employees.isEmpty())
    {
    employees.add(e);
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
    for (i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
    {
        if (employees.get(i).getAge() > e.getAge())
        {
        employees.add(i, e);
        break;
        }
        }
    if (i == employees.size())
        {
            employees.add(e);
        }

        checkDept(e);
    }

}



public ArrayList<Employees> getEmployees() {
    return this.employees;

}

public void setEmployees(Employees e) {
    this.emp = e;

}

}


package JAssessment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Company 
{

String name;
ArrayList<Department> department;
static ArrayList<Employees> employees;
public Company(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
    department = new ArrayList<Department>();
    employees = new ArrayList<Employees>(13);
}

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public ArrayList<Department> getDepartment()
{
    return department;
}

public ArrayList<Employees> getEmployees() 
{
    return employees;
}

public void addDepartment(Department d1) 
{
    this.department.add(d1);
}
public void addEmployees(Employees e1)
{
    this.employees.add(e1);
}

public static boolean primeNumber(int ageX) {
    if (ageX <= 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Age is not a prime number");
        return false;

    }
    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(ageX); i++)
    {
        if (ageX % i == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Age is not a prime number");
            return false;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Age is a prime number");
    return true;

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //create a new company
    //Company testCompany = new Company("Company's Employee List");
    ArrayList<Department> listB = new ArrayList(4);
    ArrayList<Employees> list = new ArrayList(13);
    Department d1 = new Department("Accounting");
    d1.setDeptName("Accounting");
    Department d2 = new Department("Marketing");
    d2.setDeptName("Marketing");
    Department d3 = new Department("Human Resources");
    d3.setDeptName("Human Resources");
    Department d4 = new Department("Information Systems");
    d4.setDeptName("Information Systems");
    listB.add(d1);
    listB.add(d2);
    listB.add(d3);
    listB.add(d4); 



    Employees e1 = new Employees();
    e1.setName("Counting Guru");
    e1.setAge(55);
    e1.setDepartment("Accounting");

    Employees e2 = new Employees();
    e2.setName("Counting Pro");
    e2.setAge(45);
    e2.setDepartment("Accounting");

    Employees e3 = new Employees();
    e3.setName("Counting Savvy");
    e3.setAge(40);
    e3.setDepartment("Accounting");

    Employees e4 = new Employees();
    e4.setName("Counting Novice");
    e4.setAge(25);
    e4.setDepartment("Accounting");

    Employees e5 = new Employees();
    e5.setName("Sales Guru");
    e5.setAge(50);
        e5.setDepartment("Marketing");

    Employees e6 = new Employees();
    e6.setName("Sales Pro");
    e6.setAge(48);
    e6.setDepartment("Marketing");

    Employees e7 = new Employees();
    e7.setName("Sales Savvy");
    e7.setAge(38);
    e7.setDepartment("Marketing");

    Employees e8 = new Employees();
    e8.setName("Hiring Guru");
    e8.setAge(58);
    e8.setDepartment("Human Resources");

    Employees e9 = new Employees();
    e9.setName("Hiring Pro");
    e9.setAge(47);
    e9.setDepartment("Human Resources");

    Employees e10 = new Employees();
    e10.setName("Hacking Pro");
    e10.setAge(46);
    e10.setDepartment("Information Systems");

    Employees e11 = new Employees();
    e11.setName("Hacking Guru");
    e11.setAge(51);
    e11.setDepartment("Information Systems");

    Employees e12 = new Employees();
    e12.setName("Hacking Savvy");
    e12.setAge(38);
    e12.setDepartment("Information Systems");

    Employees e13 = new Employees();
    e13.setName("Hacking Novice");
    e13.setAge(23);
    e13.setDepartment("Information Systems");

    Department.addEmployeeX(e1);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e2);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e3);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e4);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e5);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e6);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e7);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e8);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e9);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e10);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e11);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e12);
    Department.addEmployeeX(e13);



    list.add(e1);
    list.add(e2);
    list.add(e3);
    list.add(e4);
    list.add(e5);
    list.add(e6);
    list.add(e7);
    list.add(e8);
    list.add(e9);
    list.add(e10);
    list.add(e11);
    list.add(e12);
    list.add(e13);

    System.out.println("********** Company's Employee List **********");

    for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(x).getDepartment());

        if (x == 0)
        {
            primeNumber(e1.getAge());

        }
        else if (x == 1)
        {
            primeNumber(e2.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 2)
        {
            primeNumber(e3.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 3)
        {
            primeNumber(e4.getAge());
        }
        else if ( x == 4)
        {
            primeNumber(e5.getAge());
        }
        else if ( x == 5)
        {
            primeNumber(e6.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 6)
        {
            primeNumber(e7.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 7)
        {
            primeNumber(e8.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 8)
        {
            primeNumber(e9.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 9)
        {
            primeNumber(e10.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 10)
        {
            primeNumber(e11.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 11)
        {
            primeNumber(e12.getAge());
        }
        else if (x == 12)
        {
            primeNumber(e13.getAge());
        }

    }

    System.out.println("********** End of Employee List **********");


        }   

    }
```

1. The 1st Problem that I am having is trying to figure out how to load the Employees in the Employees ArrayList  into the Departments that they belong in that are in the Department ArrayList. This all should occur in the Company Class.
2. The 2nd problem that I am having is trying to figure out how to then run the employees that belong to the "Accounting" department and the "Information Systems" department through the addEmployeesX method that is in the Department Class. This should also all be done in the Company class.

I will take any help that I can get. I am really desperate at this point and time is winding down on me. Thank you for taking the time to read my post and for any help that is given!

Comment: The Department variable in class Employee should be of type Department I believe, not String.

Comment: Okay, Thank you!! I apprciate your help!